# Migrate azure databricks delta table to Azure Synapse SQL pool

Tags: apache-spark, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks, azure-synapse, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have compute logic written in scala databricks notebook, This notebook is being executed by ADF to create delta files by reading raw delta files from ADLS Gen2 container.

Now I need to migrate all databricks delta tables from Azure databricks workspace to Azure Synapse analytics.

Can you list down step by step approach I need to take to accomplish this task ?

Comment: Delta tables must be written on ADLS gen2 right? What if you use copy activity in ADF to copy files from ADLS gen2 to Azure Synapse analytics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are the steps to copy data from Azure data bricks delta tables to Azure Synapse using azure data factory

- Step1:  Create a data set with "Azure data bricks delta lake" connector to point to your delta table

[image]

- Step2: Create a data set with "Azure Synapse Analytics" connector to point to your Synapse Analytics

[image]

- Step3: Use copy activity. In copy activity use step1 data set as source and step2 data set as sink

Where you have the Delta files in the Azure Databricks are the source data set, just you must create the pipeline to perform the copy activity on the Datasets to reflect on the sink Datasets that will be your Azure Synapse SQL pool.
[image]

Refer this link: [Basic scenario how Copy Activity works in Azure Data Factory](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpDkxTHAhOs)

Comment: FYI this question is off-topic, as essentially a documentation request. The OP needs to show their work and specific issue(s). Best not to answer such questions, or at most post a doc link as a comment. But really you shouldn’t be posting documentation answers like this.